# Estimation of NegEntropy

Tags: pca, matlab, entropy, signal-processing, independent-component-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the different ICA algorithms. To do that, one of the measure which I use, is to estimate the non-gaussianity using [NegEntropy](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/ica/node4.html). I am trying to find a formula/function which can do this on time series EEG data. 
May I know how can I estimate it for a random variable 'x'.? And how it differs from the entropy of 'x'?
Would appreciate any reference.

Comment: I think this question will be ruled off-topic because it is software specific. Nevertheless, are you just n need of kurtosis? See https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/174236-how-to-calculate-skewness-kurtosis .

Comment: I have a matlab function to estimate Kurtosis using https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/kurtosis.html. However for negentropy it has not been easier to do.

Comment: Sho9w us the formula you are trying to use? There is an approximation given at the link in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have just added the reference page using which I estimate the Entropy. I am not sure whether i can use the entropy as an estimation for non-gaussianity instead of Negentropy.

Comment: Negentropy is not entropy. I suggest you edit the question title and body to remove reference to MATLAB, and refocus the question on how to calculate Negentropy, and its  use as a measure of  non-gaussianity.

Comment: I edited my question and many thanks.